# How can I compile a program during the execution of a QT or VS2010 application?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt-creator

I am currently developing a small grading application (for a C++ course) that will compile students' .cpp files and compare the output to a master. I'm using QT Creator to develop the UI as well as the back-end component (including some SQLite integration), and I have struggled with finding a way to compile the files automatically and discretely.

I originally developed a small application in VS2010 that utilized the VS Command Line Compiler - it works, but only in debug mode (when the program is executed from within cmd.exe). When I moved to Release, the compile command ("cl") was not recognized. Here is a small code segment:

```
int main()
{
    system("vcvarsall.bat"); // To set up VS Command Prompt environment
    _putenv("INCLUDE=<my include paths>"); // Include paths for compilation
    _putenv("LIB=<my lib paths>"); // Include paths for linking
    system("cl /EHsc \"Student1.cpp"); // Compilation code
    return 0;
}
```

When executed in Release, both "cl" and "cl.exe" are not recognized as commands. I am executing a variant of this program as a .exe file from within the QT application, passing a file name to this function, so it needs to be in Release form. What can I do to utilize the Command Line Compiler from within this application?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to find the "cl.exe" file in your environment. I believe its somewhere in VS folder

Comment: Did you try fully-qualifying vcvarsall.bat? It's unlikely to be in your `PATH`...

Comment: if I was your student,  I could do some *NASTY* things to your computer :)

Comment: @ildjarn and @Dani: I truncated my code so it would fit better. Here are the full lines: `system("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\vcvarsall.bat\""); _putenv("INCLUDE=\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\include\";\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\bin\\\";"); _putenv("LIB=C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\lib;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.0A\\Lib");`

Comment: @KeithNicholas: Ah, but I ran it in a sandbox and flunked you. :P

Comment: As a former CS student and teacher I can only say this: This approach will never ever work, unless you specify EXACTLY what the students' programs' output is supposed to look like. And even then you will probably do most of the comparison by hand, because not everybody will get this right.

Comment: The application is meant for in-class quizzes, which test very basic algorithmic functions. I stress that the syntax is precise (I've used the approach for a few years now, but only in a console application).

Comment: You could save some time and run the program from within the Visual Studio command line shortcut.  This way if your environment ever changes you are no left recompiling your system.

Comment: I maybe missing the point, but why use both Qt Creator and Visual Studio? Isn't it easier to just generate a qmake project file?Furthermore, do the students need to provide a working function, library, or application?

Answer (score 0):

I have no teaching background, but my first suggestion is to have your students provide a makefile. [NMake](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd9y37ha%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is system for VC, so you could try that.

If you still would like to compile using your own code I would recommend SCons instead of a console application. SCons and Python are free and very easy to setup. Your example becomes:

```
Program(target='Student1App', source=['Student1.cpp'])
```

You can call scons from within a C++ application if you choose, and after the call, assuming no build errors, the executable will be available.